# variable Matrix sizes java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, matrix, textbox

So I am creating a GUI with java that can add, subtract, or multiply matrices and I want to be able to adjust the size of the matrix using a combo box. I can take care of all the math pieces of it, but I can't seem to figure out how to create a variable number of textboxes in a panel.

My first question is, is what I'm trying to do at all possible? and if it is, how might I create a variable number of textboxes within the panel and be able to read in from them all, then output the necessary values to either another grid of variable size?

I realize this could be a little confusing, please feel free to ask any clarifying questions and thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<JTextField>> matrixA = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then iterate through them when you need the inputs.

Might I suggest `GridLayout` for the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Try [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Oracle's documentation is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it's a little late. It's a good idea if you can explain why you think JTable is a good idea as well. The reader can then decide whether your answer meets their question before following the link